# parsing malformed/incomplete XML in GWT

Tags: xml, gwt, gwt2

Is there a library for parsing incomplete XML in GWT?

Because the GWT XML Parser will give an exception, if it is given an incomplete/malformed XML to parse...But I have a scenario in which incomplete XML needs to be parsed. Have you faced such a scenario? How did you solve this problem, in a GWT application?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by malformed/incomplete? How bad is it? Do you just need to parse a stream of XML instead of a complete XML document?

Comment: Well, I am creating a web crawler, in which a user can specify a crawl as text following the XML ver1.0 format- what I want is, as the user types in the XML, all the nodes in the XML are shown in a tree structure. The only soln I have found so far is a java based solution (nothing in GWT)...

Comment: I'm confused why you would be writing a web crawler in GWT. This seems like something that should be running on a server.

Comment: @JasonHall - the crawler will be running on a server- but the front end uses GWT, and I thought I could make it look nice by showing the xml nodes in a tree, using GWT...

Comment: Oh, then why not, while you're parsing/crawling the XML on the server, prettying it up, or putting it into some easier to digest form that you can send to the client to display? Just a thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Incomplete XML" is a misnomer. "Incomplete/Malformed XML" is not XML, and therefore no XML parser would be able to parse this any better than a string of random garbage. A given input string is either accepted by a grammar, or it isn't -- computers are strangely binary in that way.

If the XML is incomplete in a perfectly predictable way (e.g. always missing the last character of the file), then you can mend the input string yourself before you parse it. But, in general, this is an **unsolvable problem.**